# Search for duplicate or similar node titles when creating content?

Tags: search

Much in the same way that it is on this site (as you type your question, it shows similar questions) is there a module that will search for similar nodes as I type the node title in Drupal?

I know of the [Unique Field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module, however it only checks after the node has been submitted. I need some way of doing it as they type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is module [Uniqueness](http://drupal.org/project/uniqueness) , it does exactly what you want. It allows you to enable for any content type, and you can configure checking on node add or edit or both.

> Uniqueness module provides a way to avoid duplicate content on your
>   site by informing a user about similar or related content during
>   creation of a new post. A UI widget is added to the node/add form that
>   does asynchronous searches on inputted fields (like the node title or
>   vocabularies) and returns the titles of similar content.

Comment: Awesome module, great find!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's a contributed module already. However you can create it yourself.

First you need to create/register autocomplete callback menu using `hook_menu` function.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['mymodule-autocomplete-title'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_autocomplete_title',
    'access arguments' => array('view published content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then create a function to search and retrieve similar node titles.

```
function mymodule_autocomplete_title($title) {
  $results = array();
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($title) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->fields('n', array('title'));

  $nodes = $query->execute();

  foreach ($nodes as $row) {
    $results[$row->title] = check_plain($row->title);
  }

  drupal_json_output($results);
}
```

Then alter the desired node add form using `hook_form_alter` function to change normal node title field to autocomplete node title field.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // node add form id
  if($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
    // make title field autocomplete field  
    $form['title']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'mymodule-autocomplete-title';
  }  
}
```